# zf2 translation tmx support

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-translate

The Zend Framework 2 documentation says that

The translator supports the following major translation formats:

- PHP arrays
- Gettext
- Tmx
- Xliff

I have a ZF1 application where I use Tmx format.  However, after looking at the ZF2 source code it seems that Tmx may not be supported in ZF2.  Can anyone verify this?

Comment: It appears you're right, Tmx and Xliff don't appear to be supported currently. My best guess is that this is merely an error from copy/past'ing over the old ZF1 translation and it's been overlooked as far as an update would be concerned ;)

Comment: I hope overlooked and not dropped, otherwise, migration to ZF2 will be an even bigger job.

Comment: There may be many reasons to go one way, but if there's no big reason for your company to choose Tmx/Xliff, then I'm pretty certain there's tools for tasks like "tmx to gettext" or the likes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is in fact (currently) wrong. I've created a [PR](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation/pull/991) to have them updated to show that the following are available:

- PHP Arrays
- GetText
- INI

Many aspects of ZF2 have been rewritten from the ground up and the additional support was not included at this moment.

You can find the current supported loaders here -> [I18n Support Loaders](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/I18n/Translator/Loader)